# AWS Cognito - Amplify: Auth.signIn no matter what returns NotAuthorizedException in React Native

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I just started using AWS Cognito in my App, I followed instructions and installed Amplify and created User Pool and Identity pool and set up everything.
I created a signup form and signet up with no problems with `Aut.signUp()` and confirmed email.

But when I tried logging in I entered my credentials and got NotAuthorizedException, Incorrect username or password.

I am logging in like this:

```
Auth.signIn(user.Username, user.Password)
    .then((res) => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(user))
        .then(res =>{
            console.log('saved')
        })  
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
```

No matter what I enter in input fields I get this error. I just started using Amazon AWS and can't really think of a problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after a few days of trying to solve this, I found a solution.

In AWS config by default Authentication Flow Type is set to USER_SRP_AUTH
What you need to do is in your AWS config put: 
`authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',`

And then go to amazon cognito panel -> user pool - > app clients - >show details -> Enable username-password (non-SRP) flow for app-based authentication (USER_PASSWORD_AUTH).